# Increment content of pointer

Tags: c, pointers, operators

I am trying to increment a value in C and return the old value, and I am doing that using a pointer. The problem is that the new value is still 0 even though I am using pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int increment (int *mem) {
    int tmp;
    tmp = *mem;
    *mem++;
    return tmp;
}

int main () {
    int a = 0;
    printf("The old value of a is \t %d", increment(&a));
    printf("The new value of a is \t %d", a);
}
```

Now when I run this method I get the same value for a that is 0; I was expecting 1 in the second printf. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: try `(*mem)++` then read about operator precedences

Comment: You really should learn how to use the debugger, and enable all warnings & debug info in your compiler, and read more about C syntax. Don't write some syntax that you don't master (so add parenthesis as much as you want)

Comment: BTW, I'm coding in C since the 1980s and I *never* code `*mem++` because I find it so unreadable (so I code either `*(mem++)` or `(*mem)++` or even `mem[0]++`....), even if it has some defined meaning

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this

```
*mem++;
```

to this

```
(*mem)++;
```

The problem lies in the operators priority. You may want to read about [C Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

---

So, what does your code do? It increments the value of the pointer, since `++` operator is activated first and then `*` gets activated, having no real effect.

As a result, your code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), since you access (and eventually write) into an invalid memory location since the pointer is incremented before the value is written to it.

Comment: Meant to use the C version.  I deleted it.  Didn't notice your link.

Comment: IMO, you should mention that the OP's code invokes UB.

Comment: Good idea @CoolGuy, since (s)he modifies the value of the pointer and the access it, right? That's what you mean or you had something else in mind? It's ok csnate.

Comment: Yes. The OP's code writes into an invalid memory location since the pointer is incremented before the value is written to it.

Comment: Bravo @CoolGuy, that really improved the answer, thank you. If you want something else changed in the answer, let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you missed some parentheses?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int increment (int *mem) {
    int tmp;
    tmp = *mem;
    (*mem)++; // problem was here.
    return tmp;
}

int main (){
    int a = 0;
    printf("The old value of a is \t %d", increment(&a));
    printf("The new value of a is \t %d", a);
}
```

Comment: Parentheses should be used for plural. Since I am Greek, I had to tell! :P By the way, +1 for the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what everyone else has posted about operator precedence, if you are passing in a pointer to an int to be incremented there is no reason to return a copy of the int via `tmp`. You will have access to the value in `mem` outside of the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void increment (int *mem) {
    (*mem)++;
}

int main () {
    int a = 0;
    printf("The old value of a is \t %d", a);
    increment(&a);
    printf("The new value of a is \t %d", a);
}
```